# How to add security identity (certificate + private key) to iPhone keychain?

Tags: iphone, security

How to add security identity (certificate + private key) to iPhone keychain?
I have .p12 file in application. I can get identity from it using SecPKCS12Import() but
when i try to do the following:

```
NSMutableDictionary *secIdentityParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];    
[secIdentityParams setObject:(id)kSecClassIdentity forKey:(id)kSecClass];
[secIdentityParams setObject:label forKey:(id)kSecAttrLabel];
[secIdentityParams setObject:(id)myIdentity forKey:(id)kSecValueRef];

status = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef) secIdentityParams, NULL);
```

I am getting error = -25291 -> No trust results are available.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Just use 1 parameter in attributes dictionary to add identity to keychain:

```
NSMutableDictionary *secIdentityParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];    
[secIdentityParams setObject:(id)myIdentity forKey:(id)kSecValueRef];
OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef) secIdentityParams, NULL);
```

Comment: OMG, that was it, not putting the the class attribute made it work. Why O why is the Security framework so wretchedly complicated, poorly documented and finicky? So much wasted time.

Answer (score 2):

Using kSecValueRef as the only parameter works perfectly. Do you know why the function fails when other parameters, like e.g. kSecClass, are provided? The **Keychain Services Reference** documents the first parameter of `SecItemAdd()` as follows:

> A dictionary containing an item class
>   key-value pair [...] and optional
>   attribute key-value pairs [...]
>   specifying the item's attribute
>   values.

I assumed that kSecClass is a mandatory parameter that must always be present, either when using `SecItemAdd()` oder `SecItemCopyMatching()`. [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Tasks on iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW13) explains the process of adding a `SecIdentityRef` to the Keychain as follows (Listing 2-3):

```
CFDataRef persistentRefForIdentity(SecIdentityRef identity)
{
    OSStatus status;

    CFTypeRef  identity_handle = NULL;
    const void *keys[] =   { kSecReturnPersistentRef, kSecValueRef };
    const void *values[] = { kCFBooleanTrue,          identity };
    CFDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values,
                                              2, NULL, NULL);
    status = SecItemAdd(dict, &persistent_ref);

    if (dict)
        CFRelease(dict);

    return (CFDataRef)persistent_ref;
}
```

Is this example just wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get Keychain Services to return a Persistent Keychain Reference when adding a new `SecIdentityRef` via `SecItemAdd()`. Here is the working code:

```
- (NSData *)persistentKeychainReferenceForIdentity:(SecIdentityRef)identity
{
    NSData *persistentRef = nil;
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                (id)identity, kSecValueRef, 
                                (id)kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnPersistentRef, 
                                nil];
    OSStatus itemAddStatus = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)attributes, 
                                        (CFTypeRef *)&persistentRef);
    if (itemAddStatus != errSecSuccess)
    {
        return nil;
    }    

    return persistentRef;
}
```

I hope this helps others too.

Comment: What do you do with that persistent ref?  Store it in user preferences to access it later then look up in keychain from there?